# hashmap, arraylist in java script

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am moving from android native code to phone gap.I want to store some data in local. How can I store like hash map and inside hash map another hashmap , array in javasript  just like in java?
     Thank You advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is no dedicated "type" for hashmaps in Javascript. You can just use object literal:

```
var hashmap = {
  some_other_hashmap: {
    key1: 'lorem',
    key2: 'ipsum'
  },
  some_array: [1, 2, 3],
  'not a valid JS identifier': 1
};
```

Later, you can access elements:

```
hashmap.some_other_hashmap.key1
// or
hashmap.some_array
```

Alternatively, especially if keys aren't valid JS identifiers (i.e. they contain characters not allowed in variable names), you can access them using this notation:

```
hashmap['not a valid JS identifier'] // === 1
```

Finally, if you use object literal as a hashmap, you have to be aware of the fact that each literal will contain some properties "out of the box", for instance:

```
var a = {};
a.hasOwnProperty // === function...
```

If this isn't something you want, you could use dedicated module, like [dict](https://github.com/domenic/dict) from Domenic Denicola.